# Adding whl files to an Azure Synapse spark pool

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-synapse

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/spark/pool?view=azure-cli-latest#az-synapse-spark-pool-update), we should be able to add custom libraries as follows:

```
az synapse spark pool update --name testpool \
--workspace-name testsynapseworkspace --resource-group rg \
--package-action Add --package package1.jar package2.jar
```

However, when I try this with my python package whl files, I get an error message that the package does not exist.

```
> $new_package_names = "PACKAGE1-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl PACKAGE2-1.0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl PACKAGE3-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl PACKAGE4-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl"  

> az synapse spark pool update --name $pool_name --workspace-name $workspace_name --resource-group $resource_group --package-action Add --package $new_package_names
```

I receive the following error:

```
(LibraryDoesNotExistInWorkspace) The LibraryArtifact PACKAGE1-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl PACKAGE2-1.0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl PACKAGE3-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl PACKAGE4-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl does not exist.
Code: LibraryDoesNotExistInWorkspace
Message: The LibraryArtifact PACKAGE1-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl PACKAGE2-1.0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl PACKAGE3-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl PACKAGE4-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl does not exist.
```

The same works if I have only one package in the variable `$new_package_names`.
It looks to me like Azure thinks it's all one package instead of four different ones. All four are uploaded to the synapse workspace and available for selection when I do the same process manually. Does anyone know of a fix for this issue? Does it only work for .jar files for some reason?

Comment: hi @Cribber , you can try alternative approach

Go to **Manage** -> **Workspace Packages** -> **Upload Wheel package** then -> Go to **Apache Spark pool** -> select **Packages** -> Select from **Workspace Packages**.

Comment: That is what I meant with "the same process manually" - these manual steps via the GUI work perfectly. But the CLI command somehow throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it really comes down to the format in which I pass the package names to the function. Something apparently changed internally as the previous way did not work anymore.

As [MartinJaffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/martinjaffer-msft/) from Microsoft answered in the [MS Q&A forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1034400/adding-whl-files-to-an-azure-synapse-spark-pool.html):

"""

If you are using az in powershell, there is a better way to go about this.

```
  $new_package_names = "PACKAGE1-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl" , "PACKAGE2-1.0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl" , "PACKAGE3-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl" , "PACKAGE4-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl"  
        
  az synapse spark pool update --name $pool_name --workspace-name $workspace_name --resource-group $resource_group --package-action Add --package @new_package_names
```

Here we changed new_package_names into an array type, and use the `@` **splatter operator** to seperate them.

As simpler example, it makes the following two excerpts be equivalent:

```
 Copy-Item "test.txt" "test2.txt" -WhatIf
    
 $ArrayArguments = "test.txt", "test2.txt"
 Copy-Item @ArrayArguments -WhatIf
```

"""

Utilizing the splatter operator when passing the parameters worked perfectly.